# What part of speech is the word “doped” in the phrase “highly doped semiconductor”?

Tags: grammar, parts-of-speech

What grammatical forms do "high" and "priced" take in the phrase "high priced clothing"?  Or is this "common term" simply a grammatically incorrect construction that has been accepted over time, assuming of course, that "high priced clothing" is accepted as grammatically correct.  In a similar fashion, is there a way to interpret the grammatical construction of the phrase "high-doped semiconductor" so that it would be grammatically correct?

Based on the dictionary definition of "high", it appears "high" may be used interchangeably for "highly" when used as an adverb (see below). Is this an exception? What is the difference in grammatical construction between the examples below and the phrase "high-doped semiconductor"?

> 2. Highly:
>       *he ranked high among the pioneers of chemical technology*

More example sentences:

> There is no great benefit from ranking high this year as next year there are no World Championships.
>
> It has to be said that Pas de la Casa is boring, unless getting legless ranks high on your list.
>
> What is lacking are not the resources, but the political will. It is clear these topics do not rate very high on his agenda.

Comment: @BillJ This is actually a term in the Electronics. In a layman language, *doping* here means *polluting a substance with another substance*.

Comment: I've no idea what a 'highly doped semiconductor' is, but "highly-doped" looks like a compound adjective with the past participle verb "doped" as head and the adverb "highly" as the first element. So the part of speech of "doped" is **verb**. It looks grammatical to me, though I would hyphenate the two elements as you have in your question, but not in the title. Btw, "highly-doped semiconductor" is a noun phrase, in which "highly-doped" is premodifying the noun semiconductor

Comment: Aa others answered, "highly doped" is a term in electronics/chemistry. It's grammar is similar to "lightly salted". As for "ranks high" and "rates high", the verbs "rank" and "rate" seem to be used as [copular verbs](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/copular_verb) in these examples, so they are followed by adjectives, not adverbs; compare to "looks good" or "sounds awful".

Answer (score 1):

**doped** is the past/passive participle of **dope**, which means to introduce a small amount of something that has a dramatic effect on the whole. It most common use is concerning drugs.

In the context of electronics, the base medium is normally non-conductive silicon, which is doped with a charge-carrying element (boron, aluminium, indium, arsenic or antimony) to make a semiconductor.

Participles are effectively adjectives, so you need to qualify it with an adverb **highly**. Highly doped means that a larger than normal amount of a charge-carrying element has been added.

The word [high](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/high) can be used as an adverb, but its meaning is strictly **a long way from the ground**. You cannot use it to mean **Great, or greater than normal, in quantity, size, or intensity**, which is what this phrase requires: for that, you must use **highly**. [Here is some more information](http://www.confusing-words.com/?toload=inner.Body_ConfusingWords&id=4961&BereichID=134&title=%20%3Ca%20href%3D%3F%3EConfusing%20Words%3C%2Fa%3E%20%3E%20&title2=high%20and%20highly) about the distinction between high and highly.

The issue is somewhat confused because [high-priced](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/high-priced?q=high%20priced) is an adjective in its own right, and cannot be used as a precedent for using high as an adverb to qualify other adjectives. Looking at [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=high%20charged%2C%20highly%20charged&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chigh%20charged%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chighly%20charged%3B%2Cc0), you can clearly see that highly charged is very common and high charged is negligible. The same goes for motivated, integrated, paid, sensitive and effective.

Laugh's comment about **ranked** explains that using **ranks high** is altogether different, as **rank** is a copular verb and may be followed by an adjective.